# Как передать обьект с сервера в activity через dagger?

Tags: android, mvp, dagger2, moxy, di

Начал применять Dagger2 в своем проекте на mvp(moxy) истолкнулся с проблемой.
Я получаю от сервера список объектов с полным содержимым, которые отображаю в списке; при нажатии на элемент открывается activity с детальным просмотром этого обьекта (сейчас сделано через extras).
Как я могу через dagger передать в новую activity выбранный объект?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не можете передать данный объект в вашу активити с помощью дагера. Вы можете создать сущность которая будет получать этот объект с сервера. А вот эту сущность вы можете уже передать с помощью дагера в активити как зависимость.

Исходя из того что вы задаете такие вопросы, вы не очень понимаете что такое DI (Внедрение зависимостей). Я рекомендую вам уделить этому внимание.

Comment: Интересное предложение. У меня по сути класс модели и получает данные с сервера. Где можно почитать о предоженном Вами способе, чтобы внедрить модель с полученными данными в activityсю с детализацией?

Comment: Ну это очень обширная тема чтоб ее обсуждать в комментариях. Я даже не совсем понимаю каких знаний вам не хватает. Тут и в целом понятие "Внедрение зависимостей" и вообще построение архитектуры. Почитайте статьи по Dagger, статьи по чистой архитектуре. Но это пальцем в небо советы. Я правда нет понимаю уровень ваших знаний.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что внедрить один обьект в несколько activity можно через subcomponent?

Comment: Да это один из вариантов.

Comment: https://github.com/industradamus/GCPSoftwareTestApp это мой проект с Дагером, можете посмотреть пример